# The natural map $\mathbb{S}^{2n+1}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^n$ is a submersion

Tags: differential-geometry

When I say the natural map, I mean the restriction of the quotient map
$$\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^n$$

I assume that the natural way to do this is by considering appropriate charts and computing the Jacobian of the coordinate representation of this map.

My problem is that $\mathbb{S}^{2n+1}$ here is not the "standard" subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2n+2}$ but we see it as a subset of $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ and I don't know which charts could I choose in this case.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you know that the original map is a submersion?

Comment: Yes. Does that imply that the restriction is also a submersion?

Comment: Not immediately, but you can note the path $t\rightarrow tv$ ($v\in S^{2n+1}$) maps to a constant (by definition of $CP^n$), so the direction normal to the sphere gets mapped to zero by the derivative, so it doesn't "contribute" anything to the rank of the derivative.

Comment: Hm, to be honest, I can't understand this argument. Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: For $p\in S^{2n+1}$, you can write $T_p(C^{n+1})$ as a direct sum $T_p(S^{2n+1})\oplus \mathbb{R}v$ where $v$ is a vector normal to $S^{2n+1}$ at $p$.

Comment: If $\pi$ is the quotient map, then $d\pi(T_p(C^{n+1}))=d\pi(T_p(S^{2n+1})) $ since $d\pi(v)=0$.

Comment: Could you please tell me how we derive this direct sum decomposition? (I am sorry, but I don't have much experience in Differential Geometry).